# Google Omniauth - undefined method bytesize for hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, omniauth, ruby-on-rails-7

i am trying to implement google omniauth at my rails 7 app and get the following error:

```
ERROR -- omniauth: (google_oauth2) Authentication failure! undefined method `bytesize' for #<Hash:...>: NoMethodError, undefined method `bytesize' for #<Hash:...>
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The GoogleOauth2 gem has a dependency on the oauth2 gem.
Version 1.4.7-1.4.8 of oauth2 introduced this bug, but is fixed as of 1.4.9

Updating the oauth2 gem to 1.4.9 should fix this issue.